# Can't create SimpleXMLElement object from SOAP response of PHP Soap Client object

Tags: php, soap, simplexml

I am working on project, where I get XML response from one web-service.

I used nusoap library, to grab the webservice output.

When I print that response I got proper XML output. But when I place that variable like:

```
$xml = simplexml_load_string($output->response());
print_r($xml);
```

I got empty object.
But I paste printed xml string in simplexml_load_string() I got object.

How should I use SOAP XML response in simplexml_load_string() function ?

My code was like:
require_once('nusoap/lib/nusoap.php');
$client = new nusoap_client('http://serverip.path?wsdl', true);

```
                        // Check for an error
                        $err = $client->getError();

                        if ($err) {
                            // Display the error
                            echo '<h2>Constructor error</h2><pre>' . $err . '</pre>';
                            // At this point, you know the call that follows will fail
                        }

                        // Call the SOAP method
                        $result = $client->call('getNjdgDashB', array("arg0" => 'treasury', "arg1" => 'treasury', "arg2" => 'G'));                      
                        echo $note= $client->responseData;
                        $note = str_ireplace('SOAP-ENV:',  '', $note);
                        $clean_xml = str_ireplace( 'SOAP:', '', $note);
                        $xml = simplexml_load_string($clean_xml);
                        print_r($xml);
```

Comment: The object is not actually empty, it just doesn't show up well in print_r output because it uses namespaces. See the linked reference for how to access the content.

Comment: Also, you shouldn't need a third party library like nusoap, because PHP has [built in SOAP functionality](http://php.net/soap).

Comment: My code was like:

Comment: No its empty:   My xml format: <?xml version="1.0"?>
<KAHCSTAT> <CASE> <CASE_TYPE>CCC</CASE_TYPE>
  <CASE_YEAR>2014</CASE_YEAR>
  <TOTALCOUNT>2</TOTALCOUNT>
  <SENIORCOUNT>0</SENIORCOUNT>
  <DISPOSAL_LAST_MONTH>0</DISPOSAL_LAST_MONTH>
 </CASE>
 <CASE>
  <CASE_TYPE>CCC</CASE_TYPE>
  <CASE_YEAR>2015</CASE_YEAR>
  <TOTALCOUNT>6</TOTALCOUNT>
  <SENIORCOUNT>0</SENIORCOUNT>
  <DISPOSAL_LAST_MONTH>0</DISPOSAL_LAST_MONTH>
 </CASE>
 </KAHCSTAT>

Comment: Get rid of those str_ireplace calls, use `$xml->asXML();` or https://github.com/IMSoP/simplexml_debug then read the linked answer to understand what the `SOAP:` means and how to deal with it properly.